# Unattended-Upgrade frequently reboots without logging anything

Tags: unattended-upgrades

On 22.04.1 LTS, unattended-upgrades service reboots the server frequently, sometimes within a 15-minute interval!. Everything is default, ie, I have not edited `50unattended-upgrades` or made any other changes. I have tried stopping/purging/reinstalling the service, but the reboots (as recorded by syslog) continue. I can only see the reboots from syslog using `grep 'Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown' /var/log/syslog` . A few reboots are noted in `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`, but the majority are not. Syslog shows no other errors other than what appears to be a normal reboot by unattended-upgrades.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1451030/edit) to include the complete output of: `grep Reboot /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

Comment: You could let `unattended-upgrades` send mail to yourself. That may help you find out what is going on.